# call $scope.watch function only after focusout of the field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im new to angular and im looking for a way to call function, currently called after every change, only after focus is out of that field. the purpose of this function its to check if user changed the data in  certain `<td>` and only if he changed data function should execute. problem is now every key press calls the function so if use adds 2 chars to string in the `<td>` it will execute twice.

this is my table:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(user_id,script_id) in data">
    <tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in script_id">
        <td class="userName">{{user(user_id)}}</td>
        <td class="scriptName">{{script(script_id)}}</td>
        <td class="cronFormat"><input type="text" ng-model="cron_format" ng-change="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format)"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and this are the functions:

```
$scope.$watch('cron_format',function(x,old){
    if(x!=old){
    }
});

$scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat){

   $.post("updateCronChange.php",
        "user_id="+userId+"&script_id="+scriptId+"&cron_format="+cronFormat, 
         function(data){
        //inside post
            alert('cron format changed to:'+cronFormat);
   });
}
```

any angular way i can call saveCron() only after focus out of the 
field (cron_format)??

Comment: Dont use jQuery `$.post` in Angular app! It won't trigger a `$digest` cycle! And you can create a directive to handle the `focus` problem. `app.directive("focus"`

Answer (score 6):

And one more solution for Angular 1.3.x is to use `ngModelOptions` to instruct to update the model only on focusout event:

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="cron_format" 
       ng-change="saveCron()" 
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'focusout', debounce: {'focusout': 0} }"/>
```

Comment: Thanx.. it helped me  i used  <input name="{{row.id}}" type="text" ng-model="row.name" class="form-control"
               ng-if="row.editing && row.name_editing"
               ng-change="updateSession(row);row.editing = false;row.name_editing = false;"
               ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur mouseleave', debounce: {'blur': 0, 'mouseleave': 500} }">

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're talking about ng-blur

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

Comment: i tried in ng-blur but when i asked how to compare the old value to the new i got the answer i should check out ng-watch :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the ng-blur directive instead of ng-change in the view. That way you call saveCron everytime the input field loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a `$watch` (although you could) but instead compare to another changed value.  You can use `ng-blur` to trigger the change check.

```
$scope.old = $scope.cron_format = "";

$scope.saveCron(user_id, script_id, cron_format) {
    if ($scope.old == $scope.cron_format) {
        return; //value was unchanged
    }
    $scope.old = $scope.cron_format;
    $http.post();
});
```